# Browse sort criteria

Tags: upnp, dlna

I'm trying to write a upnp/dlna client for videos and I would like to allow the option to sort by title and date.

With Windows7/wmp as the server, I can use "dc:title" or "dc:date" for sorting and it seems to work but testers have told me it doesn't work on other servers. Is there a universal way to know if sorting is allowed and what the sorting criteria should be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to query this (but be prepared for broken implementations that lie about their abilities as well). Quoting [ContentDirectory service spec (v3)](http://upnp.org/specs/av/UPnP-av-ContentDirectory-v3-Service.pdf):

> 2.3.3
>   SortCapabilities
>
> This state variable is a CSV list of property names that the ContentDirectory service can use to sort
>   Search() or Browse() action results. An empty string indicates that the device does not support any kind of
>   sorting. A wildcard (“*”) indicates that the device supports sorting using all property names supported by
>   the ContentDirectory service. The property names returned MUST include the appropriate namespace
>   prefixes, except for the DIDL-Lite namespace. Properties in the DIDL-Lite namespace MUST always be
>   returned without the prefix. All property names MUST be fully qualified using the double colon (“::”)
>   syntax as defined in Section 2.2.20, “property”. For example,
>   “upnp:foreignMetadata::fmBody::fmURI”